How do dvaitins explain the Gita verse 15.7?
ममैवांशो जीवलोके जीवभूत: सनातन: |
मन:षष्ठानीन्द्रियाणि प्रकृतिस्थानि कर्षति || 7||
Krishna here says jivas are his eternal fragments.
Fragments(amshas) can only take place when the jivas were undifferentiated whole(i.e there was only god before and jivas physically seperated from him like sparks from fire)  before and later seperated..can someone shed light about how various Acharyas interpret the verse..also personal interpretations are welcome..

Commentaries by various Acharyas: https://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-15-7/

Clearly he is not saying he jiva is equal, What one should understand by the word sanatha, on which forever, Both God and Jiva existed for forever, how, God is all kowing without flaw, but jiva is less than God, here sanata word exclude advaita only one Brahman is there, secondly when there is God with all quality why there is need for multiple jivas with the same quality. its highly unlikely. that the new Jiva God will be idol even though it had realised and become god, this jiva god before realizing undergoes all the changes which is impossible as per sruthi God doesnt under go change.

this excludes vasita advaita also

Even by the above if jiva god before reaching moksha undergoes changes means is he anyway equal to who is not changing.. so vasita advaita also falls by the above

Here amsha stands for sadrusha amshaa.. he is similar in one aspect not same.. like not getting dukkha
